# Why does this function always return 0?

Tags: c++

I have a function that is always returning 0.  The problem I believe is that data is an unsigned char, which is not part of the library. It needs to be unsigned char. So how can I make this work, because what I have doesn't.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int Count( const std::string & str, 
           const std::string & obj ) {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0;
    std::string ::size_type pos = 0;
    while( (pos = obj.find( str, pos )) 
                 != std::string::npos ) {
        a++;
        b++;
        c++;
        d++;
    pos += str.size();
    }
    return a;
    return b;
    return c;
    return d;
}
void printTcpContent(unsigned char *data,int)
{
    std::string s = (const char*) data;
    int a = Count( "text/html", s );
    int b = Count( "text/plain", s );
    int c = Count( "image/jpg", s );
    int d = Count( "image/png", s );
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have four variables doing exactly the same thing? only a will get returned.

Comment: What is the value of "data" when you call printTcpContent?

Comment: Data returns this... -------------IP Data Begins-------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OKP3P: policyref="http://g
oogleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/gcn_p3p_.xml"
, CP="CURa ADMa DEVa TAIo PSAo PSDo OUR IND UNI
PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniffContent-
Encoding: gipDate: Mon, 29 Aug 201
1 21:19:36 GMTServer: cafeCache
-Control: privateContent-Length: 4863
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block    Second response.  Not true I always get 4 returns back. And they are correct.

Comment: I tested this before the induction of data.  In a seperate VS solution and it worked beautifully.  Once I moved it into my other project and had it search data. Thats when the problem started.  I don't believe it's reading data.

Comment: @ME-dia: You do not get four returns back from `Count`. You call `Count` four times. `b`, `c` and `d` inside `Count` are _completely meaningless_.

Comment: You should add the extra information about what is in 'data' to the question, rather than in a comment.  You can edit your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
int Count( const std::string & strToFind, 
       const std::string & strToSearch ) {
    int n = 0;
    std::string ::size_type pos = 0;
    while( (pos = strToSearch.find( strToFind, pos )) != std::string::npos ) {
        n++;
        pos += strToSearch.size();
    }
    return n;
}
```

Also, you can test it works by calling it with smaller test strings, eg Count("3", "1234534")

Comment: I tried it and it returns all zero's.  I think the problem is with data. It's an unsigned char and Count doesn't reconize it.  So in reality it's searching nothing.

Comment: @ME-dia: So, in reality, you haven't narrowed this problem down enough to answer. Do some debugging please.

Comment: @ME-dia: you can add diagnostic prints to Count to see what it gets to work on.

Comment: I've done debugging and the problem is the "unsigned char *data. This is whats causing the problem. Jonathan how would I do that?  I'm still kinda new to this. Thank you.