# how to get datetime from gettimeofday in C?

Tags: c, gettimeofday

how to get datetime from gettimeofday in C?
I need convert tv.tv_sec to Hour:Minute:Second xx without functions  such as localtime and strftime  ..., just get it by computing. for instance tv.tv_sec/60)%60 will be minute

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

int main ()
{
  struct  timeval tv;
  struct  timezone   tz;
  gettimeofday(&tv,&tz);
  printf("TimeZone-1=%d\n", tz.tz_minuteswest);
  printf("TimeZone-2=%d\n", tz.tz_dsttime);
  printf("TimeVal-3=%d\n", tv.tv_sec);
  printf("TimeVal-4=%d\n", tv.tv_usec);
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %d-%d\n", (tv.tv_sec%    (24*60*60)/3600,tz.tz_minuteswest);

    return 0;
  }
```

how to get the current Hour of system by computing tv and  tz, also to get Minute, Second and MS
~

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: `time_t` is seconds since the beginning of a day - universal time.  This is commonly Jan 1, 1970 UTC of which the code is assumed to be using given `sys/time.h`

The main idea is to extract from each member of `tv,tz` the data to form local time.  Time-of-day , [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), in seconds from `tv.tv_sec`, minutes from timezone offset and hour adjustment per DST flag.  Lastly, insure the result is in the primary range.

Various type concerns include the fields of `tv` are not specified as `int`.

Avoid using magic numbers like `60`.  `SEC_PER_MIN` self-documents the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define SEC_PER_DAY   86400
#define SEC_PER_HOUR  3600
#define SEC_PER_MIN   60

int main() {
  struct timeval tv;
  struct timezone tz;
  gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
  printf("TimeZone-1 = %d\n", tz.tz_minuteswest);
  printf("TimeZone-2 = %d\n", tz.tz_dsttime);
  // Cast members as specific type of the members may be various 
  // signed integer types with Unix.
  printf("TimeVal-3  = %lld\n", (long long) tv.tv_sec);
  printf("TimeVal-4  = %lld\n", (long long) tv.tv_usec);

  // Form the seconds of the day
  long hms = tv.tv_sec % SEC_PER_DAY;
  hms += tz.tz_dsttime * SEC_PER_HOUR;
  hms -= tz.tz_minuteswest * SEC_PER_MIN;
  // mod `hms` to insure in positive range of [0...SEC_PER_DAY)
  hms = (hms + SEC_PER_DAY) % SEC_PER_DAY;

  // Tear apart hms into h:m:s
  int hour = hms / SEC_PER_HOUR;
  int min = (hms % SEC_PER_HOUR) / SEC_PER_MIN;
  int sec = (hms % SEC_PER_HOUR) % SEC_PER_MIN; // or hms % SEC_PER_MIN

  printf("Current local time: %d:%02d:%02d\n", hour, min, sec);
  return 0;
}
```

Output sample

```
TimeZone-1 = 360
TimeZone-2 = 1
TimeVal-3  = 1493735463
TimeVal-4  = 525199
Current local time: 9:31:03
```

Comment: why tz_minuteswest always return 0?

Comment: @Colin In which time zone is your computer?  (where are you?)

Comment: Wed, 03 May 2017 11:40:24 +0900, and it seems timezone setting is correct. ZONE="Asia/Seoul"
UTC=false
ARC=false

Comment: @Colin Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/q/28375324/2410359 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/7343622/2410359 and see `Data Type: struct timezone` in ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/glibc-2.2.3/html_chapter/libc_21.html

Comment: hmm, do you know some work around way for this problem?

Comment: @Colin Sorry, no.